# centering div of unknown width inside a div

Tags: html, css

I have a wrapper div element that contains a div that in turns contains divs inside; these divs are added or removed at runtime. The HTML and CSS look like this:

```
​<div id="Wrapper">
   <div class="InnerGreen">
       <div class="InnerContent"></div>
       <div class="InnerContent"></div>
   </div>    
</div>

​#Wrapper{
     width:600px;
     height:50px;  
     margin:10px 20px;    
     background:blue;}

.InnerGreen{
     background:green;
     margin:10px auto; // this doesn't center
     overflow:hidden;
     display:inline-block;}

.InnerContent{
     background:yellow;
     height:30px;
     width:40px;
     float:left;
     margin:3px 5px;}
```

I'm using `inline-block` to wrap the `.InnerGreen` inside the `Wrapper`; however, the `margin:auto` don't seem to horizontally center the div. Of course, this works if I define the width of `.InnerGreen` but in reality, the `.InnerContent` divs are a collection of divs of all different sizes so I can't set the width of `.InnerGreen` at runtime.

How can I make the `margin:auto` work? Here the the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f6XYk/).

Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Inline elements have no margins. By telling `.InnerGreen` to act as `inline-block`, you're essentially telling it to act as inline with regards to positioning. On the other hand, you can still center it using text-align:

```
#Wrapper {
    text-align: center;
}
```

See [updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f6XYk/6/).

Comment: The InnerContent divs are not text: they contain other divs.

Comment: @frenchie -- Doesn't matter. They're inlined, so they'll position as inlined, which can be centered using `text-align`.

Answer (score 2):

This may not technically be the right way of doing it, but you could put `text-align:center` on your wrapper div.

Comment: The InnerContent divs are not text: they contain other divs.

Comment: @frenchie - but because they're acting as inline elements, you can style them as if they *were* just text ... such as using `text-align: center`.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know, without being able to determine the width of the element, you cant use the margin:auto method. It isn't exactly elegant, but you can accomplish this with a centered table:

```
<center>
   <table>
    <tr><td align="center">
       <div>This will be centered.</div>
    </td></tr>
   </table>
</center>
```

with your code:
http://jsfiddle.net/MaxPRafferty/yA7Nm/

Answer (score 0):

You could just center the div using jquery, something along the lines of...

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function() {
        var containerWidth = $(".InnerGreen").width();
        $(".InnerGreen).css("width", containerWidth);
    });
</script>
```

Your CSS setting for the margin should then do the rest.

You may also want to add height: auto to your style, as if you are adding internal content at runtime, it will better control the growth of the element.